# Ethernet Print Server to connect to Multifunction USB device

Tags: windows-8, network-printer

Any advice about whether an Ethernet Print Server will allow a Multifunction USB device to work and if so is there anything we need to be careful of when buying the Print Server?

The actual senario is a Canon MP610 on a Server 2012 Hyper-V host and a Windows 8 virtual machine.  Problem is no driver available for Server 2012 so only way I can see around this would be a print server so that win8 can print directly.

Also would the scanning facilities still be usable over a print server?

Answer (score 1):

The MP610 is a GDI printer (which lacks intelligence to convert the page into dots on the page, and uses the Windows graphics engine instead). These printers are inherently hard to network. Often the only way is to share them via a PC. [This link](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100012601.html) has a driver that's claimed to work with Win 8. Alternatively, you could try the Win 7 driver on the Win 8 machine.

If you want to use a printserver, you need to make sure it supports your printer. For each printserver, go to the manufacturer's website. There should be a list of supported printers for each printserver. If the list is not there, or if your printer is not in the list, you must assume that it will not work.

Scanning will almost never work with any printserver.

Comment: Yes, I have a 64-bit Windows 8 driver just not a Server 2012 driver and the Win 8 driver causes all sorts of problems when installed on Server2012.

Comment: That's another part of the fun and games with GDI printers: their drivers are much more dependent on the exact version of the OS. And yes, without a driver on the server, the poor Win8 guy has no way of accessing the printer. I would plug it into a PC, share it and skip the server.

Comment: Bit of a long shot but I wonder if I could install this on a Linux machine and have the Windows 8 connect to it there.

Comment: It should work if there is a cups driver

Comment: I believe there is, will give that a go then.  What I don't know yet is whether I install the printer driver on the Win 8 machine and point it towards the IP number of the Linux machine (like a hardware ethernet print server) or whether I connect as a more traditional shared network resource.

Comment: I've been wondering about that as well. Your point is valid: the linux server would be no more than a printserver, so it should not work. I've never heard of anyone trying it though, so it is worth a test.